# Formulae for $\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\binom{n}{2k}(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Given a complex number $z=a+bi$, its $n$th power can be written in closed form as $$(a+bi)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
2k
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}+i\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
2k+1
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k-1}b^{2k+1}.$$

So I was wondering if there were formulae for $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
2k
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\
2k+1
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k-1}b^{2k+1}?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac12\left((a+bi)^n+(a-bi)^n\right)$$ and similar for the other one.  Or did you want a formula without complex numbers?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for formulae without complex numbers. Thanks.