# What is the general form for complex numbers raised to whole number powers?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation, exponentiation

Say I have a complex number, $a+bi$, and I want to raise it to a whole number power $n$. I know I can calculate it as: $$(a+bi)^n= \sum_0^n{n\choose k}a^{n-k}(bi)^{k}$$
However, I want to be able to calculate the real and imaginary parts separately, for reasons dealing with computer programming that are irrelevant to the question.
I attempted this with:
$$\Re\{(a+bi)^n\} = a^n-\sum_1^{\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor}{n\choose 2k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}$$ and $$\Im\{(a+bi)^n\} = i\sum_0^{\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil}{n\choose 2k+1}a^{n-(2k+1)}b^{2k+1}(-1)^k$$
But I am 100% convinced I have made a mistake and lost the plot on what I'm trying to do.

Am I correct in my thinking? And if not, how could I fix these equations?

Comment: It seems OK, but you need to get rid of the $i$ in front of the summation in the imaginary part

Comment: Although this isn't explicitly helpful to your question, since you wanted to calculate the real and imaginary parts separately, you could much more easily calculate $(a+bi)^n$ by converting it into the polar form $(m,\theta)$ and then outputting $(m^n,\theta*n)$ and converting back into coordinates. Very computationally efficient in comparison to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Take a look at this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1761023/264):

> Given a complex number $z=a+bi$, its $n$th power can be written in closed form as $$(a+bi)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
> n\\
> 2k
> \end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k}b^{2k}+i\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor }\left(\begin{array}{c}
> n\\
> 2k+1
> \end{array}\right)(-1)^{k}a^{n-2k-1}b^{2k+1}.$$

Comment: In testing it appears that the real part of the function needs to be divided by 2

Answer (score 2):

Write the number in polar form:

$$a+ib=z=|z|e^{it}\implies z^n=|z|^ne^{int}\implies$$

$$\text{Re}\,(z^n)=|z|^n\cos nt\;,\;\;\text{Im}\,(z^n)=|z|^n\sin nt$$

...as simple as that!

Comment: For technical reasons, I have to use the $a+bi$ form

Comment: @script8man And you will...after passing through the polar form...:) Unless, of course, for some misterious reason, you are *forbidden* to use the polar form.

Comment: Floating point precision makes it so that the polar form gets messed up

Comment: @script8man I see...well, in fact I don't. I loathe numerical analysis. :) Thanks.

Comment: I decided to +1 your answer because even though it doesn't help in my case, anybody referring to this thread would find it useful